# Find out the dimension of $\frac{a}{b}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

> $E=b-\frac{x^2}{at}$  [x=distance,t=time, E=energy]

I have tried following but don't know whether I am correct or not

$$\frac{x^2}{at}=E$$

$$\frac{L^2}{aT}=ML^2T^{-2}$$

$$a=M^{-1}T^{1}$$

Please help to solve these problem.

Comment: Hi Freddy. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic i thought 'homework' tag include only question which are given in a homework that's why i had also made featured request in meta for making self-learning tag <http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/should-there-be-self-learning-tag>

Comment: @Freddy: No, it's not just for tasks assigned as homework. In fact, it would be impossible to implement such a tag, think about it? How could we determine if a teacher/prof assigned that task?

Comment: @JamalS if we think in that way then you are right so it is better that also homework like question should be homework question.

Comment: I have edited the question and added **homework** tag. I have already shown the effort done by on the question before asking it. So i request to remove **on hold** from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the found  dimension of $a$ is incorrect. $a$ is in the denominator. You forgot to divide the dimention of $a$ by one. Solving:
$$\left[\frac{x^2}{at}\right]=\left[E\right]$$
$$\left[a\right]=\left[\frac{x^2}{Et}\right]$$
$$\left[b\right]=\left[E\right]$$
$$\left[\frac a b \right]=\left[\frac{x^2}{E^2t}\right]=\frac{(L)^2}{(ML^2T^{-2})^2T}=\frac{T^3}{M^2L^2}$$